# Is it possible to edit .resx file manually?

Tags: development, timer-jobs, resource-files, resources

I have a resourcefile in the SharePoint 14 hive called `SPMailRevision.resx`.

(`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\`)

I have a solution that refers to this resx file via these xml tags:

```
<data name="email_body_text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Please look over this document:</value>
      </data>
```

The mail sends out perfectly with this text, but when I change the text within the value tag nothing happens.

```
 <data name="email_body_text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>New text</value>
  </data>
```

Is the resx file somehow copied to the web application. Or is the text somehow cached?

Comment: did you do an iisreset after changing the value?

Comment: No I havent done that. Ive been reading some more on the net and it seems it caches the result. http://www.jkstack.com/2013/12/resourcemanager-getstring-vs-sputility-getlocalizedstring-sharepoint.html

Where do I find the cache? I can't do a IISRESET before tonight.